# PHPExcel load file from link

Tags: php, excel

Is there a way that i can load the file from url, not from local directory ? I red somewhere here, that it isn't accepting http protocol, but what do i need to change to fix that ? Or maybe use something like curl to parse the file somehow to the load event ?

Just i need some way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do this (php5):

```
file_put_contents('filename.xls', ­ 
  file_get_contents('http://www.mysite.com/file.xls')
);
```

then continue using filename.xls in PHPExcel.  At the very end you can delete the temporary filename.xls file.

Comment: I didn't want to make new files and write to them, but it looks like this is the only option for now, so .. i didn't do it with file_put_contents still, i used fopen, and at the end of the functionality i used unlink to delete so.. thnx anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Use cURL or file_get_contents to download the file locally, then do what you need to do with PHPExcel